# Interpreting binned scatterplot (R) and calculating variance of the mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, bin, variance

I am trying to plot the simulation result against the samples. Therefore, I have many data points - so I opted for the binned scatterplot. It was suggested in one of the papers to plot the binned plot in order to calculate the first-order effect by calculating the variance of the coloured points.
My plot looks like this:

I used the code for this plot from here:
[making binned scatter plots for two variables in ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947210/making-binned-scatter-plots-for-two-variables-in-ggplot2-in-r)

However, I do not quite know how to interpret the plot. I understand that the coloured points are the average of the bins but what does it actually tells us about the data and how do I further calculate the variance of these yellow points?

Can we imply from this plot that the variables show (weak) linear relationship even though some of the yellow points do not really follow the trend?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Binned scatter plot]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the interpretations of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: sure. will do so from now on. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bin the data by the `cut()` function as follows,

```
mybin <- cut(df$x,20,include.lowest=TRUE,right = FALSE)
df$Bins <- mybin
```

Then to calculate the mean of the binned data,

```
library(tidyverse)

out<- df %>% group_by(Bins) %>% summarise(x=mean(x),y=mean(y)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

To compare our results with the `stat_summary_bin()` function of the `ggplot2` we can plot them together,

```
(ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun='mean', bins=20,
                   color='orange', size=2, geom='point') +
     geom_point(data = out,color="green"))

# green dots are the points we calculated. They are perfectly matching.
```

[image]

Now, to calculate the variance, we can simply follow the same process with the `var()` function. So,

```
 df %>% group_by(Bins) %>% summarise(Varx=var(x),Vary=var(y)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

gives the variance of the binned data. Note that, since the x axis is binned, the variance of x will be almost zero. So,the important one in here is the variance of the y axis actually.

- The variances of the binned data gives us a mimic about the [heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) of the data.
- The path of the binned mean also shows the pattern of the data. So your data have a positive trend. (No need to see a perfect smooth line). But it becomes weaker because of the different means around as you suggested.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1000)
y <- x^2 + x + 4 * rnorm(1000)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

**Note:** The data and some of the ggplot2 codes have been taken from the OP's referred [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947210/making-binned-scatter-plots-for-two-variables-in-ggplot2-in-r).

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to explain this. I really appreciate it. I do have further questions regarding this (if you allow).  Is it necessary for the value we calculated to match the values we obtained from the stat_summary_bin()?  - Regarding the interpretation: Would it be correct to assume that the yellow points we calculated is the expected mean of Y given X and the sum of the variance would be the total variance of the expected mean given x. Additionally, in my case, the variance of x did not turn out to be zero. Is it considered normal? Thank you very much once again!

Comment: 1)It should be, but not necessary since I don't know the exact calculation way of the `stat_summary_bin()` function.  2) Yes, E(Y|X) is the mean  of the each group separately.(But note that binning is actually assuming the x values are more or less same  for each bin). 3) When it comes to variance, I am not sure, but you can simply prove it by suming up and comparing. 4) It is normal you haven't got zero variance in x axis, because your x axis is between 0 and 150. My example was between 0 and 1. If you increase the bin size, you get values closer to 0. Bin size is all up to you.

Comment: Hi again, I thought I understood the variance part but clearly I have not and wanted to ask you how can I prove that it is a total variance by just summing them up? (Sorry if my question does not make sense)

Comment: You asked "sum of the variance would be the total variance of the expected mean given x?". And I wanted to say that you have the variances and data set. So you can prove or disprove your claim by just summing up. (You said the "sum of the variances". That is why I used "summing up" refering to it)