# Putting a best fit line through a binscatter in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data.table

Piggy backing off of this [great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947210/making-binned-scatter-plots-for-two-variables-in-ggplot2-in-r), I am hoping to introduce a best fit line through the orange lines from robust's answer. I understand that I can connect the lines by adding another stat_summary_bin with `geom = "line"`, but this generates a line that goes through each point, and I am looking for a best fit line through these points, if this is even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use binsreg to do this: https://nppackages.github.io/binsreg/. binsreg can plot the best fit line or other parametric fits.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).