# how to bin multiple variables for scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, bins

It's hard to determine the relationship between these variables, so I'd like to bin them. I've found [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947210/making-binned-scatter-plots-for-two-variables-in-ggplot2-in-r) explaining how to bin two variables, but not seven. I'm also not sure how to tailor it to my dataset.
Is there a way to alter this to bin multiple variables?

Mine (Note that the data in my photo is the transformed version of the dataset I have below):

```
diabetes = read.csv('https://github.com/bandcar/Examples/raw/main/diabetes.csv')
pairs(diabetes)
```

Advice:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1e4)
y <- x^2 + x + 4 * rnorm(1e4)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

library(ggplot2)
(ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y='mean', bins=20,
                   color='orange', size=2, geom='point'))
```

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: The easiest way to avoid massive overplotting here would be to use a random subsample of the data

Answer (score 0):

The comment from shs may actually be the right answer.
Programmatically speaking though, what about having one plot by pair of variables of interest?

```
library(GGally)
library(data.table)
diabetes = read.csv('https://github.com/bandcar/Examples/raw/main/diabetes.csv')
setDT(diabetes)

ggpairs(
  diabetes, 
  lower = list(
    continuous = "smooth",
    combo = "facetdensity",    
    mapping = aes(color = Outcome)
  )
)

vars <- colnames(diabetes)
vars <- vars[! vars %in% c('Age', 'Outcome')]
colpairs <- t(combn(vars, 2))

r <- 1
for (r in 1:nrow(colpairs)) {
  v1 <- colpairs[r, 1]
  v2 <- colpairs[r, 2]
  ggp <- ggpairs(
    diabetes[, .SD, .SDcols = c(v1, v2, "Outcome")], 
    lower = list(
      continuous = "smooth",
      combo = "facetdensity",
      mapping = aes(color = Outcome)
    )
  )
  print(ggp)
}
```